# Condition for $8p+1$ divides $2^p-1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test, mersenne-numbers

Here is what I observed :

Let $8p+1 = (2a-1)^2+64(2b-1)^2$ with $a$ and $b$ be a positive integers, $p$ and $8p+1$ both prime numbers.

Then $8p+1$ divides $2^p-1$ only if you can write $8p+1$ as $(2a-1)^2+64(2b-1)^2$.

For example :

- $89 = (2 \cdot 3 - 1)^2+64(2 \cdot 1 - 1)^2$ and $89 = 11 \cdot 8+1$ so $89$ divides $2^{11}-1$
- $233 = (2 \cdot 7 - 1)^2+64(2 \cdot 1 - 1)^2$ and $233 = 29 \cdot 8+1$ so $233$ divides $2^{29}-1$
- $3449 = (2 \cdot 22 - 1)^2+64(2 \cdot 3 - 1)^2$ and $3449 = 431 \cdot 8+1$ so $3449$ divides $2^{431}-1$
- $137 = (8 \cdot 17 + 1)$ but you can't write $137$ as $(2a-1)^2+64(2b-1)^2$ so $137$ does not divide $2^{17}-1$

For the moment, I didn't find a counterexample with this condition.

I need help for proving it but I don't know how to start.

I thought about Mersenne numbers and Sophie Germain primes that say if $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and $2p+1$ is prime then $2p+1$ divides $2^p-1$ but for $8p+1$ it doesn't work.

If you found a counterexample please tell me.

Comment: This is [A122095](http://oeis.org/A122095)

Comment: To your question, of course any prime is the sum of two squares, hence we can write $8p+1=n^2+m^2$ for some $n,m\in \mathbb N$.  Now exactly one must be odd, so let's say $n$ is odd.  If $m$ were divisible by $2$ but not by $4$ then we get $8p+1\equiv 5 \pmod 8$, a contradiction.  So $m$ is divisible by $4$.   I don't immediately see how to show that $8\,|\, m$ nor that $16\,\nmid\, m$.

Comment: @lulu any prime that is 1 (mod 4) (including these), not any prime at all

Comment: @GregMartin  Yes, of course.  That's for the correction.

Comment: No counterexample upto $p=10^8$

Comment: No idea whatsoever why this was downvoted (+1)

Comment: **Note:** Basically the same question is now also on MathOverflow at [Condition for $8p+1$ divides $(2^p+1)/3$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/428134/129887).

Comment: $$2^p-1=2kp+1\land 2kp+1\equiv 8p+1\pmod{8p+1}\implies k\equiv 4\pmod{8p+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be useful to find a proof but if $p$ and $1+8p$ are  prime numbers and  $2^p-1 \equiv 0 \bmod {(1+8p)}$ then

$2^{p+1} \equiv 2 \bmod {(1+8p)}$

$(2^{\frac{p+1}{4}})^4 \equiv 2 \bmod {(1+8p)}$ if $p \equiv 3\bmod4$

$(2^{\frac{p+3}{4}})^4 \equiv 8 \bmod {(1+8p)}$ if $p \equiv 1\bmod4$

in the first case, [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiquadraticReciprocityTheorem.html) you will find information on why $1+8p=x^2+64 y^2$

Answer (score 1):

for an odd prime $p$, if a prime $q$ divides $2^p − 1$, then $q \equiv 1$ (mod $2p$). also $q$ $\equiv \pm 1$ (mod $8$).

in the last example of $M_{17}$ which is a Mersenne Prime, the only valid option for $q$ is the number itself which is $(8*16384) - 1$. for all of these $M_{13}$, $N_{19}$ naturally $q \equiv - 1$ (mod $8$). I don't know if that's a useful place to start from, as in - only for non prime $2^p - 1$, $q \equiv \pm 1$ (mod $8$).

Edit: saw [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428134/condition-for-8p1-divides-2p1-3) now, that makes sense. I was thinking of it only working for mersenne numbers that aren't primes, but that only eliminates a subset of $M_p$ (it works for prime $M_n$ too)